# Adding cell to bottom of UI Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `CollectionView` to display `array` of message, but I want the cells to start displaying from the bottom. Example is WhatsApp or Telegram App for iOS (new messages starts from the bottom and populate upwards).

I am trying to transform my collection view:

```
messageCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: (-(CGFloat)(Double.pi)))
```

And then transform collection cell at cellForItemAt :

```
cell.transform = self.messageCollectionView.transform
```

But when I insert a new cell, transform cell does not appear in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

I usually achieve the effect your trying to accomplish by inserting the cell at the last index with the animation of you choice.

To achieve this just utilize `insertItems(at:)` method. For further reading follow [apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618097-insertitems)

Comment: I am using insertItems(at:) method. Inserted cell does not transform after inserting. Cell transform only after collection dragging and handling cellForItemAt method.

Comment: This link has an example https://dzone.com/articles/animating-inserts-and-deletes

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this you're looking at creating a custom UICollectionViewLayout.

This answer should point you in the right direction:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31286238/346098

Also Apple provide a tutorial for creating custom layouts:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html